# How can I configure TYPO3 9.5.5 Rootpage with a Slash only (fix the /1 bug)?

Tags: typo3, slug, typo3-9.x

I'v installed TYPO3 9.5.5 on a stage server, where everything works right till I configured the slugs and the sites configuration.

If I want to configure the slugs of the root page with a slash `/` TYPO3 saves it with a slash one `/1`.

So if I know go into the frontend and load the rootpage of my site I get a 404 Error.

I think that is because TYPO3 makes the /1 thing.

If I now load the page with stage.myserv.de/1 TYPO3 navigates to the correct rootpage.

How can I fix this please.

All my other slugs like stage.myserv.de/band works fine after editing it.

I tried also to make a "workaround" with sites configuration using the `/1` as rootpage. Now the rootpage works, but all other pages have the "prefix" `/1` in it like stage.myserv.de/1/band and so on, but the first `/1` isn't editable anymore.

Hope someone could help.

Best Thanks

Comment: Do you have multiple root pages? Perhaps you have two with the same base URL or language base URL. TYPO3 assigns a number suffix to routes to prevent duplicates.

Comment: I only have one language on my site.

Comment: And only one root page.

Answer (score 1):

this bug is is related to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87884 and is worked on afaik